# Linq join missing columns

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, select, c#-4.0

I have two tables.

**TableA**

```
TableAId value value2
 1        a     b
 2        aa    bb
 3        aaa   bbb
```

**TableB**

```
TableBId TableAId  Status 
  1        1       success
  2        1       success
  3        2       failed
  4        2       failed
```

I am trying to create **list** like

```
   TableAId value value2 successCount errorCount
     1        a     b       2           0
     2        aa    bb      0           2
     3        aaa   bbb     0           2
```

This is the query i am writing

```
from a in db.TableA
join b in db.TableB on a.TableAId equals b.TableAId
group b by a into g
select new
{
    TableAId = g.Key.TableAId,
    value = g.Key.value,
    value2 = g.Key.value2,
    successCount = g.Count(t => t.Status == "success"),
    errorCount = g.Count(t => t.Status == "failed")
}
```

From the above query i am getting the following result

```
  TableAId value value2 successCount errorCount
     1        a     b       2           0
     2        aa    bb      0           2
```

The problem is that I am missing those records where there is no Hid record in table B. In this case I am missing **TableAId: 3 record**

How to include those records which is only in Table A and does not have any record in Table B.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use group join to get records from tableB which are related to record from tableA (join tables by TableAId). And then just select count from group of tableB records:

```
from a in db.TableA
join b in db.TableB on a.TableAId equals b.TableAId into ab
select new {
    a.TableAId,
    a.value,
    a.value2,
    successCount = ab?.Count(t => t.Status == "success") ?? 0,
    errorCount = ab?.Count(t => t.Status == "failed") ?? 0
};
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "TableAId": 1,
    "value": "a",
    "value2": "b",
    "successCount": 2,
    "errorCount": 0
  },
  {
    "TableAId": 2,
    "value": "aa",
    "value2": "bb",
    "successCount": 0,
    "errorCount": 2
  },
  {
    "TableAId": 3,
    "value": "aaa",
    "value2": "bbb",
    "successCount": 0,
    "errorCount": 0
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need the [linq equivalent of a left outer join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ee908647.aspx#leftouterjoin). (another good example is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397895.aspx))

so, for example:

```
from a in db.TableA
join b in db.TableB on a.TableAId equals b.TableAId into c
from d in c.DefaultIfEmpty()
group b by a into g
select new
{
    TableAId = g.Key.TableAId,
    value = g.Key.value,
    value2 = g.Key.value2,
    successCount = g.Count(t => t.Status == "success"),
    errorCount = g.Count(t => t.Status == "failed")
}
```

You may need to add something additional into the select new {...} portion to handle null values for successcount/errorcount, I'm not sure, not where I can test it right now.

Answer (score 1):

You need to perform a left join and use `into` / `from` / `DefaultIfEmpty()`

```
from a in db.TableA
join b in db.TableB on a.TableAId equals b.TableAId into bg
form b in bg.DefaultIfEmpty()
group b by a into g
select new
{
    TableAId = g.Key.TableAId,
    value = g.Key.value,
    value2 = g.Key.value2,
    successCount = g.Count(t => t.Status == "success"),
    errorCount = g.Count(t => t.Status == "failed")
}
```